# every time i want to access my WordPress website it redirect automatic to admin panel what should i do?

Tags: wordpress

i am working on a website using local xamp server. how can i access my work because if i hit URL  like localhost/WordPress or  localhost/WordPress/wp-admin in these both case there is only admin panel not original website.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the front end of your website from admin panel you simply go to the top left corner of your admin panel. There you'll find your website name and If you click the name, it will redirect you to your site.

hope this helped :)